# Passing the `ng-repeat` element to javascript function

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want to pass the ng-repeat element to javascript function tried but it is not working

```
 <tr ng-repeat="x in myArry">
                <td><input type="text" value="{{x.firstname}}" id="{{x.firstname}}{{$index}}" onblur="FirstNamseCon(this.id, {{x.firstname}}{{$index}})" /></td>
                <td><input type="text" value="{{x.lastname}}" id="{{x.lastname}}{{$index}}" onblur="FirstNamseCon(this.id, {{x.lastname}}{{$index}})"></td>
                <td><input type="text" value="" id="{{x.fullname}}{{$index}}"></td>
                <!--<td><label id="{{x.fullname}}{{$index}}"></label></td>-->
            </tr>
```

this my javascript function

```
function FirstNamseCon(value1,value2) {
        document.getElementById('B Madhukar0').value = document.getElementById(value1).value + ' ' + document.getElementById(value2).value;
    }
```

I want to pass the name last name id to function using  `{{x.firstname}}{{$index}}` but I am getting `x` is undefined error how to solve this

Comment: first of all you are using angularjs so you dont need to assign data like native javascript function. Second post your html also or make a fiddle

Comment: you have whitspaces in your ids... You aren't using angularjs... I think that you need to study how to stay in an angularjs life cycle!

Comment: no my requirement is like that i will add javascript function i need to call that function like this. that is possible or not

Answer (score 1):

A angular solution will be to use `ng-model` to update the values

```js
var app = angular.module('my-app', [], function() {})

app.controller('AppController', function($scope) {

  $scope.myArry = [{
    firstname: 'John',
    lastname: 'Thomas',
    fullname: 'John Thomas'
  }, {
    firstname: 'Arun',
    lastname: 'Johny',
    fullname: 'Arun Johny'
  }]

  $scope.updateFullName = function(x) {
    x.fullname = x.firstname + ' ' + x.lastname
  };
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="my-app">
  <div ng-controller="AppController">
    <table>
      <tr ng-repeat="x in myArry">
        <td>
          <input type="text" ng-model="x.firstname" ng-change="updateFullName(x)" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" ng-model="x.lastname" ng-change="updateFullName(x)">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" ng-model="x.fullname">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I know this approach but i am dng modifications with value field in javascript function thats why i am using value all are working fine but passing FirstNamseCon(this.id, {{x.firstname}}{{$index}}) not working

Answer (score 0):

use angulars `ng-blur` insted `onblur` and write your `FirstNamseCon` in controlles as `$scope.FirstNamseCon`

Comment: here i am calling javascript function not a angular function

Comment: is there any reason for doing it?

Answer (score 0):

> Doing DOM manipulation inside controller considered as bad pattern,
>   don't dare to do that if you wanted to manipulate scope variable's
>   from jQuery.

Use `ng-model` over the input field to get two way binding feature of angular and then you could easily pass the value of scope `ng-model` value to your controller.

Also make you function available inside a scope by having, `$scope.FirstNamseCon = FirstNamseCon` exposed `FirstNamseCon` method in scope by assigning its reference to scope variable.

**Markup**

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in myArry">
    <td><input type="text" ng-model="firstName" ng-clur="FirstNamseCon(firstName)" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" ng-model="x.lastName" ng-blur="FirstNamseCon(x.lastName)"></td>
    <td><input type="text" ng-model="x.fullName" ng-blur="FirstNamseCon(x.lastName)"></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `ng-model` instead of `value`. Just change your code something like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in myArry">
            <td><input type="text" ng-model="x.firstname" id="{{x.firstname}}{{$index}}" onblur="FirstNamseCon(this.id, {{x.firstname}}{{$index}})" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" ng-model="x.lastname" id="{{x.lastname}}{{$index}}" onblur="FirstNamseCon(this.id, {{x.lastname}}{{$index}})"></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="" id="{{x.fullname}}{{$index}}"></td>
            <!--<td><label id="{{x.fullname}}{{$index}}"></label></td>-->
        </tr>
```

But you don't have to use the `onblur` for this.

Comment: I know this approach but i am dng modifications with value field in javascript function thats why i am using value all are working fine but  passing  FirstNamseCon(this.id, {{x.firstname}}{{$index}}) not working

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this -

```
 onblur="FirstNamseCon('firstName',$index,x)
```

and in your javascript code you can get id like this.

```
var id = x[type]+index;
 // A['firstName']+0
```